# File not found.Typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to the implementation of Typescript in new React projects.

I ran `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`, and I would like to know what are all the files that do not serve me and I can delete. As with js, I delete everything and only keep app.js, app.css and index.

However when I did it here I get an error.

The error tells me:

```
undefined TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined): File '/mnt/d/NodeJs/my-todo-list/src/App.test.tsx' not found.   The file is in the program because:
    Matched by include pattern 'src' in '/mnt/d/NodeJs/my-todo-list/tsconfig.json'  TS6053
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-todo-list",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "typescript": "^4.1.2",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to know everything I could delete to start a new project in react with typescript, including if I can delete the files
react-app-env.d.ts
reportWebVitals.ts

Tree src:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to your editor settings.json (cntrl + shitf + p in vscode for win), then put and save

```
"typescript.validate.enable":true,
```